# Count letters in sentences (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

i'm a beginner programmer, and i want to ask about count the many letters in a sentence.
For the example program like this :

```
data = "Hello World"
s = input() # Try to input L

Output :
L = 3
```

So the output is just what i input, not with other letters like w, o, r, d, h, e. I wrote some code but i dont know why the output sometimes `None` or `11` or `0`. Here the code i write with output `0`

```
data = "Hello World"
s = input()

sum = 0
for s in data :
    if s == data :
        sum += 1
print(sum)
```

Any suggestion for what i can do to write the program like i want ?

Comment: Your input is `s`, and your for loop also iterates using `s`. Try using `for x in data: if s == x` etc.

Comment: Your description of your problem is not clear enough, nor either is easy to figure-out what do you want to really achieve, with the code you have written. It's not clear what are you trying to do. You should provide an example of input data, and then specify what are you expecting to be the output

Comment: Okay sorry for that all, i already fixed it and i'll make it more clear in my next question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not wrong, what I understood from your problem is that you wish to count the total number of times an alphabet appears in a string and then  print the total number of times it occurred in the sentence.

In order to achieve this, I can show you two methods:

Method 1:
Naive approach:

```
data="Hello World"
s=input() # Assume you put 'l'
count = 0
  
for i in data: 
    if i == s: 
        count = count + 1
print(count)
```

Doing so, you will get output as 3

Method 2:
Using count():

```
data="Hello World"
counter = data.count('l')
print("Count of l in data is : " +  str(counter))
```

Hope this answered you query.

Comment: Oh wow thank you so much, i already tried it and yes this is what i want to know

Comment: glad to help you out, please select this answer as the correct one and upvote. That would help me out in turn!